# How to add different items in ScrollView in Kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy

i am creating an Android app that do the Daily Task application.

Actually I have stucked in a section, can you help me how to do it in Kivy?

### What is my problem?

Please first of all see the UI of my application.

[image]

As you can see, in the white box there should be scroll view, it means user can scroll between tasks (white box section)

Now, i have created one task label with code below in **kv** file:

```
        Label:
            id : add_task_status
            # this is for background label
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            size_hint: None,None
            size: dp(220), dp(35)
            pos: self.parent.width/2-110, root.winheight-200
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: self.background_color
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [(10, 10), (10, 10), (10, 10), (10, 10)]
        Label:
            # this is for little boxes right side
            id: task_done
            background_color: root.r,root.g,root.b,root.a
            size_hint: None,None
            size: dp(25),dp(25)
            pos: self.parent.width/2+80, root.winheight-195
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: self.background_color
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [(7, 7), (7, 7), (7, 7), (7, 7)]
        Label:
            # this is for text to show in label
            font_name: "fonts/Nunito-Light.ttf"
            text_size: self.size
            text: root.my_task
            size_hint: None,None
            size: dp(220), dp(35)
            pos: self.parent.width/2-100, root.winheight-192
```

how can i make it **dynamic**? when user add new task, it create a new label and add it under the before label

**Many Thanks!**

Comment: provide a good description about what you want and what you tried and provide a simple runnable code

Comment: Think that is a Google Task application but simple one. i want that when user type something in input box (top section) and when hit Add, the task that user have entered, shows in the middle section. as you can see it has some labels (purple background color, text input and little boxes next to each label), how can i make it dynamic, when user add another task, those labels generate in new positions? i hope you understand, if don't please let me know. Thanks @HussamF.Alkdary

Comment: @HussamF.Alkdary

Comment: @ Mahdi your question is not clear and can you provide with a minimum reproducible code ?

Comment: @Ctrl7 bro, for example in the middle section (in the white rectangle) we have just "Watch Python", how can i make it dynamic that when user add more inputs, it automatically add under the last task (Watch Python). i have created that part (in the white rectangle) with labels as you can see in my kv codes, hope you could help me, Thanks

Comment: @Ctrl7 could you check please

Answer (score 0):

Since your code wasn't reproducible I'm using a mock of your case

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv="""
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory

<label_1@Label>:
    text:"Added Label"
    
ScrollView:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical' 
        spacing:110
        size_hint_y:None 
        adaptive_height:True
        height:self.minimum_height        
        id:layout_1                 
                   
        Label:
            text:"hello"
        Label:
            text:"hello"
        Label:
            text:"hello"
        Label:
            text:"hello"
        Label:
            text:"hello"                   
        Label:
            text:"hello"
        Label:
            text:"hello"
        Label:
            text:"hello"
        Label:
            text:"hello"
        Label:
            text:"hello"                   
        Label:
            text:"hello"
        Label:
            text:"hello"   
            
        Button:
            text:"Add"
            size_hint:None,None      
            on_press:                  
                root.ids.layout_1.add_widget(F.label_1())        
                
                                                    
"""

class Main(App):           
                
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

Main().run()
```

- if you want ScrollView to adjust itself how much to scroll you should set

```
size_hint_y:None
```

Edit:
While using ScrollView some widgets for eg Button might  not be clickable or be too small , to solve this
You should either set `size_hint:None,None` or to a required size